# Equivalent of -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I succeed to display gradient to a text using the following line in Chrome

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 50%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

But I can't find the equivalent for Firefox, any help would be appreciated, thanks !
I heard about

```
 -moz-linear-gradient
```

But what should I do with the "-webkit-mask-image" part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [can i use browser support page for CSS Masks](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks).

Firefox has full support for `mask-image` and doesn't need a vendor prefix (which are only provided for experimental implementations that should not be used in production) at all.

Comment: Awesome website thanks for the tips ! So I just remplace -webkit-gradient by -moz-linear-gradient ?

Answer (score -2):

Firefox usually needs "-ms-" in pleace of "-webkit-" prefix but you don't have to use it always. Some styles doesn't require it.

I recommend you to check out sites like 
http://pleeease.io/play/ or
https://autoprefixer.github.io/ if you are not sure what to write.

Comment: `ms` stands for Microsoft, Firefox does not support it.

Comment: Yes, think he/she was thinking about moz instead of ms

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, I felt that I messed something up... I also didn't mean that "styles" per se don't require prefix, it's dependant on browser support. As you wrote, firefox has the full support so OP can't find it because it's simply unnecessary.